# Type of member variable should depend on constructor argument's type

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, lvalue, type-deduction

I try to define a class `A` as follows:

```
template< typename T >
class A
{
  public:
    A( T elem )
      : _elem( elem )
    {}

  private:
    TYPE _elem; // "TYPE" should be either "T" in case "elem" is an r-value or "T&" in case "elem" is an l-value.
};
```

Here, I want `_elem` to have either the type `T` in case that the constructor's argument `elem` is an r-value or the type `T&` in case `elem` is an l-value.

Does anyone know how this can be implemented?

Comment: I'm not clever enough to write this out for you, but you achieve this using template *specialisation*. Upvoted to attract attention.

Comment: I've had a need for this as well (when writing view classes)...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Until we get [template argument deduction for class templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html), you'll need to use a helper function for this:

```
template <typename T>
auto make_a (T&& elem) {
    return A<T>{std::forward<T>(elem)};
}
```

This uses a forwarding reference to deduce whether the argument is an lvalue or rvalue and constructs the `A` by perfectly forwarding the argument. Taking `int` as an example, if an lvalue is passed, `T` will be `int&`, and if an rvalue is passed, `T` will be `int`.

Your `A` template should just look like this:

```
template< typename T >
class A
{
  public:
    A( T elem )
      : _elem( elem )
    {}

  private:
    T _elem;
};
```

You could make `make_a` a friend and make the constructor private if you only want to allow construction from the factory method.

Comment: Why is std::move using in constructor of A?

Comment: When an r-value is passed, why is T then `int` and not `int&&`?

Comment: @abraham_hilbert that's just how the normal template deduction rules work. The `int&` deduction is a special-case.

Comment: I think this deduction is now integrated in standard C++, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction (CTAD)